# How to install polymer3?

Tags: windows, frontend, polymer, upgrade, web-component

Following the instructions from [Polymer site](https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/install-3-0) Polymer has been seemly properly installed on my Win10 machine. However outcome of `polymer --version` is `1.9.11` instead of 3.x.
How could polymer be upgraded to 3.x?

Answer (score 0):

`polymer --version` returns the `polymer-cli` version rather than the version of Polymer itself. `1.9.11` is the latest version of `polymer-cli` which is used to build Polymer 3 components.

However Polymer is no longer being developed - [LitElement](https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/) is the successor to Polymer, from the same team.